# Событие Elapsed Таймера

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Делаю секундомер который должен работать в отдельном от GUI потоке, но выводить в `label` время. Секундомер должен работать параллельно остальным операциям GUI :

```
    DateTime date;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //запуск таймера
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        date = DateTime.Now;
        long tic = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks;
        DateTime stopwath = new DateTime();
        stopwath = stopwath.AddTicks(tic);
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:ff}", stopwath);
    }
```

Выходит ошибка `СrossThreadMessagingException`. Как её исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                       label1.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:ff}", stopwath);
                }));
```

Comment: Я бы форматирование тоже вынес выше по коду, чтобы в гуевом потоке выполнялось _только_ присваивание.

Comment: Ничего не меняется

Comment: Что вы хотите выводить? `tic` всегда будет равен 0, потому что у вас `tic = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks` а `date = DateTime.Now` то есть `tic` у вас разница между одинаковыми величинами. По этому и `stopwath`  всегда будет 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ты не можешь обращаться в GUI из другого потока.

GUI привязан к потоку в котором был создан.

Тебе нужно воспользоваться `Invoke` или `async/await`

Comment: можешь дать пример?